# How to do a cors request to a node app in Bluemix

Tags: node.js, cors, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

i'm making a nodeapp on bluemix that is bounded to the business rules service and i have another application hosted on mobilefirst where i created my application UI. and i want to send data from the mobilefirst application and receive data, i've been told to use a cors request but i don't know how to do this.

here is my **app.js** file :

```
var app = require("express")(),
restler = require("restler"),
bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(request, response, next) {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});


app.post("/", function(request, response) {
    var options = {
        username: "resAdmin",
        password: "replace"
    };

    var url = "https://brsv2-6855bc66.ng.bluemix.net/DecisionService/rest" +  "/vacationsRuleApp/1.0/vacationsRuleProject/json";

    restler.postJson(url, request.body, options).on('complete', function(data) {
        response.send(data);
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8080);
```

and here is my **client code** :

```
$.post( 
    "http://businessrules-vacationsruleapp.mybluemix.net/",
    {
        "employeeID": "jujuju",
        "loanAmount": 10517320,
        "theEmployee": {
        "seniority": 3,
        "annualSalary": 10517320,
        "nbOfExtraVacationDaysBasedOnSeniority": 10517320
    },
    "creditAmount": 20000,
    "__DecisionID__": "string",
    "AnnualSalary": 20000 },
    function( data ) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to include the following in `app.js`.  The following will allow CORS on requests.

**app.js**

```
var app = require("express")(),
 restler = require("restler"),
 bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(request, response, next) {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});


app.post("/", function(request, response) {
    var options = {
        username: "replace",
        password: "replace"
    };

    var url = "https://brsv2-6855bc66.ng.bluemix.net/DecisionService/rest" + "/vacationsRuleApp/1.0/vacationsRuleProject/json";

    restler.postJson(url, request.body, options).on('complete', function(data) {
        response.send(data);
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8080);
```

Then client side with JQuery you could do the following.

```js
$.ajax ({
    url: "https://businessrules-vacationsruleapp.mybluemix.net",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ 
    "employeeID": "jujuju",
    "loanAmount": 10517320,
    "theEmployee": {
        "seniority": 3,
        "annualSalary": 10517320,
        "nbOfExtraVacationDaysBasedOnSeniority": 10517320
    },
    "creditAmount": 20000,
    "__DecisionID__": "string",
    "AnnualSalary": 20000 }),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
        $(".result").text(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Whatever object you send from the post call will get sent to the Business Rules Service.

Answer (score 1):

The CORS npm module makes this very easy to use with Express.

```
var express = require('express')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors